# Cannot constrain Card's height with SizedBox

Tags: flutter, dart

When used inside ListView, Card's width can be controlled with a SizedBox, but height stays unbounded. I would like to know how to limit it.

```dart
Widget buildCard(String text) {
  return SizedBox(
    height: 220.0, // this does not work
    width: 180.0, // this works
    child: Card(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          ListTile(
              title: Text('Title: $text'),
              subtitle: Text('Subtitle: $text'),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  );
}

Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return MaterialApp(
    // ...
    home: Scaffold(
      // ...
      body: ListView(
        children: [
          buildCard('one'),
          buildCard('two'),
          buildCard('three'),
          buildCard('four'),
          buildCard('five'),
        ],
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

A demo is available [at DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/b6409e10de32b280b8938aa75364fa7b).

Comment: unfortunately, this does not help

Comment: ok, you need to `Center` your `SizedBox`, not `ListView` - that way `SizedBox` sizes your `Cards` properly

Comment: Using Center for a SizedBox did not work for me. And a correct solution has already been suggested.

Comment: i simply used `return Center(child: SiizedBox(...))` and it worked just fine - [understanding constraints](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/layout/constraints) is a good material to read about layout management used by flutter - check all 29 examples

Comment: My bad. Your suggestion with Center does work. I forgot to put the constraint back in place after some experiments.

Comment: check `example 3` why it works and compare it with `example 2` - of course you can use any `Align` or similar widgets, not only `Center`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give `height` to `ListView` only

```
SizedBox(
        height: 220,
        child: ListView(
        //....
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped! Do you happen to know why constraint on the card itself does not work?

Comment: Because ListView content take full height irrespective of your constraint on the child widget

Comment: Now I see... The docs say: "In the cross axis, the children are required to fill the ListView."